# curl not working in xampp localhost

Tags: curl

CURL Not working perfectly. I edit php/php.ini & apache/php.ini file. But still no solution.

Comment: what is your exact problem?  Any errors or symptoms we can see?

Comment: did you restart your server?
does it give an error?
what exactly have you done so far?

Comment: Which.. platform? XAMPP version? Apache version? PHP version?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone around still needing the solution:

> 1. Go to xampp install directory.
> 2. Go to **php.ini** in **php directory**.
> 3. Open php.ini and find curl, uncomment the first find you see. Save
>      and close file.
> 4. Go to **php.ini** in **apache directory**.
> 5. Repeat Step Three.

Source: http://gabrieljones.com/getting-curl-to-work-in-xampp/

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you running.  I know that some versions shipped with a dodgy curl extension