# Is curl of php package included in xampp and guide to use appannie

Tags: php, api, curl, xampp, restful-authentication

I have just downloaded the latest xampp and it is my first time to use curl.
I have an account in appannie and have read one of the posts here regarding his/her attempt to access appannie.

Here is the link of that post:
[Appannie api basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575242/appannie-api-basic-authentication)

Well, to make it simpler here is that code he made:

```
<?php

$whmusername = "username";
$whmpassword = "password";

$query = "https://api.appannie.com/v1/accounts";

$ch = curl_init();
// Sets the URL cURL will open
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
// Here's the HTTP auth
// The 3rd argument is your Twitter username and password joined with a colon
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $whmusername.":".$whmpassword);
// Makes curl_exec() return server response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// And here's the result XML
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// inserted: echo 'hello';
print $response;
// inserted: echo 'world';
?>
```

I tried to use that but nothing happened. So i inserted echo (which i have labeled in the comment) both before and after response to see if my php network is really working and it just displayed:

```
hello world
```

So i was wondering if curl library in xampp and have read this post:
[curl not working in xampp localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996705/curl-not-working-in-xampp-localhost)

In the comments were the steps but what i found out was the curl in php.ini in php dir is already not in comment form and there was no php.ini in apache dir.

And i the 1st post that i referred regarding appannie, i have already change the username into the email account used in appannie.

Please any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are three different `php.ini` files that require modification for the cURL library to work on XAMPP.

1. `C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini`
2. `C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini`
3. `C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini`

You need to uncomment (if not already) the line for cURL Extension:

```
  ;extension=php_curl.dll
  ^----- remove semi-colon
```

Once you've made the change, you'll need to restart XAMPP.

Also, make sure that there are two files in your Windows `system32` folder: `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`. If these files are missing, you can copy them over from the PHP folder.

Hope this helps!